# Downloading Excel spreadsheet of database in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, maatwebsite-excel

I have a button, that when pressed, it should download the table I want in an excel format. The excel document downloads, but it is blank. What can I do to make it download the contents of my table.

Note: I am using Laravel 8

Here is my code:

controller:

```
use App\Models\Models\Energy;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

  public function export() 
    {
        $energy = Energy::orderBy('energyid', 'desc')->paginate(5);
        return Excel::download($energy, 'users.xlsx');
    }
```

view button:

```
 <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{{ route('export_excel.excel') }}">Export User Data</a>
```

routes:

```
Route::get('/export_excel/excel', 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\EnergyController@export')->name('export_excel.excel');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a paginated collection would work. Try using `get()` instead:

```
public function export() 
{
    $energy = Energy::orderBy('energyid', 'desc')->get();
    return Excel::download($energy, 'users.xlsx');
}
```

Comment: It still downloads a blank document

Answer (score 0):

```html
public function export() 
{
    $energy = Energy::orderBy('energyid', 'desc')->get();
    return Excel::download($energy, 'users.xlsx');
}
```

Comment: This also returns a blank excel spreadsheet. is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Its because you need to pass a dedictaed Export object, not just a collection ([Here you can check it how](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/collection.html)). Also you may consider [exporting from query](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/from-query.html) rather than from collecion.

```php
amespace App\Exports;

use App\Models\Energy;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class EnergyExport implements FromCollection
{
    public function collection()
    {
        return Energy::orderBy('energyid', 'desc')->all();
    }
}
```

```php
return Excel::download(new EnergyExport, 'energy.xlsx');
```

Comment: this returns a blank excel sheet